# How would I write this MySQL query for products?

Tags: mysql

I have 3 dropdown boxes, and I want to make a query depending what the user chooses. But what happens if they don't choose any option for the dropdown boxes?

I want to display all products where `product=`*`first dropdownbox`*, and `price` is between `$first` and `$last`, but I'm unsure how to do that.

```
SELECT * FROM Products where product=$rec AND PRICE >=$first AND PRICE <=$last
```

Comment: Concerning the first point, you'll need to _validate_ the form on the client-side with Javascript. If they fail to choose an appropriate value, you'll be able to stop the submission and ask the user designate what they want before they continue. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what you're asking, but I'm guessing you want something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Products where product=$rec AND PRICE between $first AND $last.
```

As I said, I'm not quite sure about what you're asking for.

Comment: now that its edited by Miguel i think the code i provided should do it